# How to route a record\event based on content

Tags: apache-nifi, minify

Using GetFile I’m collecting files that include JSON records. Each record includes a parameter (let's name it Sensor) that have the Value A or B.

Based on that value I wish to route each record to a different output port – which module I should use? Do I need to split the records or I can stay at the level of the file?

An example of a  record that can be found in the file

```
{"EventTime":"2020-12-07 04:49:00",

"Sensor":"A",

"Keywords":-9223372036854775808,

"EventType":"INFO",

"SeverityValue":2,

"Severity":"INFO",}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [PartitionRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PartitionRecord/index.html) with a dynamic property 'Sensor' with value `/Sensor`.

If you have 1 FlowFile with 100 Records, which are 20 Sensor A and 80 Sensor B, you'd end up with 2 FlowFiles:
FF1 = 20 Records of Sensor A, with an Attribute 'Sensor' = A
FF2 = 80 Records of Sensor B, with an Attribute 'Sensor' = B

Then you could RouteOnAttribute on the 'Sensor' attribute.

Alternatively, [QueryRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryRecord/index.html) will let you write a SQL-like query against the records and route the results to a Dynamic Relationship. You could add a Dynamic Property 'SensorA' with value `SELECT * FROM FLOWFILE WHERE Sensor = 'A'`, which will send all Records with Sensor = A to a Dynamic Relationship called 'SensorA'. Then add another Dynamic Property for Sensor B. (I didn't test that SQL, adjust as needed)