# Nifi: Filter flow files by content

Tags: apache-nifi

I have about 2000 flow files from REST API calls in json format. One file looks like:

```
[ {
  "manager_customer_id" : 637,
  "resourceName" : "customers/673/customerClients/3158981",
  "clientCustomer" : "customers/3158981",
  "hidden" : false,
  "level" : "2",
  "manager" : false,
  "descriptiveName" : "Volvo",
  "id" : "3158981"
} ]
```

Now i want to filter them by parameter `manager`. If `manager` **is true**, i should skip this flow file. So i need to work with flow files where `manager` **is false**. How to do this with Apache Nifi?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to route a record\event based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65195628/how-to-route-a-record-event-based-on-content)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your flowfile, to a record with the help of [ConvertRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ConvertRecord/index.html).
It allows to pass to an Json format to whatever you prefer, you can still keep Json format.

But with your flowfile beeing a record you can now use additionnal processors like:
[QueryRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryRecord/index.html), so you can run SQL like command on the flow file:

> "SELECT * FROM FLOWFILE WHERE manager=true"

I recommand you the following readings:

- [Query Record tutorial](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Running-SQL-on-FlowFiles-using-QueryRecord-Processor-Apache/ta-p/246671)
- [Update Record tutorial](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Update-the-Contents-of-FlowFile-by-using-UpdateRecord/ta-p/248267)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `EvaluateJSONPath` (to store the value of manager in attribute) and `Route on attribute` ( to filter based on that attribute), Direct the flow from `Manager=true` to auto terminate and proceed with the rest to success.